# Installing lxml using pip fails on openshift

Tags: gcc, pip, lxml, openshift

I'm running a django site on a virtualenv on Openshift and had no problems until I did an update which required installing lxml. After adding that to requirements, I noticed that deploy script fails. Deploy script is where a new virtualenv is built if needed, and now installing the new requirements fails with lxml.

Error message is:

```
> python setup.py install
Building lxml version 3.2.5.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
/var/lib/openshift/52c877afe0b8cdcd7e000069/app-root/data/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing src/lxml.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/lxml.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/lxml.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
writing manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -s -DNDEBUG -O3 -s -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/lxml-3.2.5/src/lxml/includes -I/var/lib/openshift/52c877afe0b8cdcd7e000069/app-root/data/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_4data':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97814: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxData' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97415: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_6start':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97951: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxStart' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97115: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_8end':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98009: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxEnd' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97339: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_10pi':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98167: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxPi' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97455: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_12comment':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98220: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxComment' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97581: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140191: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138126: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT':
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141589: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138126: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'  
gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
```

In addition to a git push, I have tried pip install lxml, easy_install lxml and building from sources, and all of these have the same outcome.

On Openshift Online, I have a DIY cartridge and a Postgres cartridge if that has anything to do with it.

I have searched all day and so far nothing. Has anyone else encountered this? Is the process being killed because it uses too much memory?

Comment: Can you provide more of the error message? Especially the one where you try to compile it yourself might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I created another DIY app and installed on it just Python 2.7.6, virtualenv and lxml to a new virtualenv. Then I just downloaded the compiled lxml from the new app and uploaded to the original app and it worked perfectly.

Hopefully this helps if someone also bumps into this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the newest version of lxml (3.5.0) requires more memory which exceeds the 512 MB provided with small gear and it adds more features into the packages. As a result, that version can only be installed in medium gear or bigger unfortunately